# React Semantic UI Dropdown open on bottom

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui

```
<Dropdown
      text={employeeOptions.find((e) => e.key === selectedEmployee)?.text as string || t('roomDetails.selectEmployee')}
      value={selectedEmployee}
      selectOnBlur={false}
      scrolling
      fluid
      options={employeeOptions}
      onChange={onEmployeeChange}
      disabled={disabled}
      className={styles.employeeDropdown}
    />
```

My task is to make this dropdown only open to bottom (even if there is no space).

Currently on the bottom its open like this:

```
[Option1]
[Option2]
[Option3]
[Dropdown]
```

But i want to open it on the bottom like this:

```
[Dropdown]
[Option1]
[Option2]
[Option3]
```

Comment: Where do you store the `employeeOptions `? If you just sort it in the order you want it should work

Comment: The order doesn't matter, dropdown is a field which opens list of options.

Comment: Sorry did read your question wrong. See a example below how to prevent upward dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Set `upward={false}` to prevent it to open upwards. See [official documentation here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-upward-selection)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const options = [
  { key: 1, text: 'One', value: 1 },
  { key: 2, text: 'Two', value: 2 },
  { key: 3, text: 'Three', value: 3 },
]

const DropdownExampleUpwardSelection = () => (
  <Dropdown
    upward={false}
    search
    selection
    options={options}
    placeholder='Choose an option'
  />
)

export default DropdownExampleUpwardSelection
```